# Cancel main without closing ghci

Tags: haskell

I'm working on a web server using [Scotty](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty). I can run `ghci` and keep using `:r` to get it to reload my code, but if I even run `main` I cant' restart the web server without killing ghci.

How can I cancel `main` without closing `ghci`? Is there a better way to handle web servers and automatically restart them?

Comment: Does `CTRL-C` or `CTRL-D` work?

Comment: Also, are you calling `main` directly, or calling it as `:main`?

Comment: CTRL-C kills ghci as well as main. I'd like to only kill main, but keep ghci open with my context. I'm calling main directly I think. (Just typing `main` in)

Comment: Try it with `:main`.  Just like `:reload`, it's a special directive in GHCi that runs `main` properly instead of executing it as an `IO` action.  It might help.  @danidiaz looks like he has a pretty good suggestion too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Invoke `:set args <arg> ...` in `ghci` to set the arguments that will be returned by `System.getArgs`.

Then, using the `async` package, launch the server in `ghci` with something like `a <- async main`.

Later invoke `cancel a` to kill the server.

See also [this link](http://chrisdone.com/posts/ghci-reload) that explains how to reload code even while the server is running.